# Java netty io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup not found

Tags: java, exception, jar, netty, classnotfoundexception

I get an exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup

when trying to start my server from runnable jar file, it works fine in IDE, but not in jar version. I don't understand why this is happening. What is missing here ? I use intellij and maven.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>Tcp-Server-listener-application</groupId>
<artifactId>TCPSLA</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Listener</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.29.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
        <artifactId>mvvmfx</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Source.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: are you trying to run a spring boot project ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to run a simple JavaFX project.

Comment: Are you running the jar version from command line ?

Comment: @MINIKAS and where do you use netty?

Comment: @Gauntam To see the exception yes, then I can see whats going on.

Comment: @Srini I'm initializing Netty server as soon as I press "Start" button, it simply trying to create a server `TCPServer = new TCPServer(viewModel,Integer.parseInt(PortField.getText()));`

Comment: I guess you are not packaging the netty jar along with your project? can you unjar your project and see if you included it?

Comment: @MINIKAS  can you share the pom.xml

Comment: @Srini if it should be on \META-INF\maven then no, can't see netty.

Comment: @MINIKAS there is some problem with your pom.xml. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

While I can offer no explanation as to why it compiles, as did mine, but fails at runtime, I can offer a solution that worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

Apparently, '4.1.29.Final' does not include EventLoopGroup